# Interpreting Algorithm for Semi-supervised Multiclass Adaboost

Tags: semi-supervised-learning, adaboost

I'm trying to implement a version of the algorithm described in [this paper](http://bit.ly/1SqmbYM) but I'm a little unsure of how the loss function is actually utilized. It defines its loss function as

$L(Y^l,Y^u,H) = \sum_{i=1}^{n_{l}+n_{u}} \exp(-\frac{1}{K}Y_{i}^TH(x_{i}))$

but in their description of the overall algorithm (detailed below), there's no mention of where the loss function is actually called in updating the predicted classes. Is the function implied as part of updating the values for the weights, $\beta$, and predicted class label ($P^{(m)}(x)$) or am I missing the point completely?

## Algorithm Steps

#### Inputs

- D: training set with labled and unlabled examples
- $n_{l}$: number of labeled examples
- $n_{u}$: number of unlabeled examples
- M: maximum number of iterations

  #### Initialize
- Weights for labeled and unlabeled examples
- Assign pseudo-class to unlabled examples using KNN with K=1
- $H^{(0)}(x) = 0$

#### For m =1,2,...,M:

#### Step 1:

Train multi-class base classifier (Decision Tree) $P^{(0)}(x)$ using labeled data and weight $w_{i}^{(m-1)}$

For this I'm using sklearn's implementation of a Decision Tree Classifier, passing in weights (initialized to the values of 8 and 2 for labeled and unlabeled samples respectively).

#### Step 2: Evaluate

$P^{(m)}(x_{i}), i = 1,2,...,n_{l} + n_{u}$

The returned classes for each sample are transformed into a k-dimensional vector where $y_{k} = 1$ if the class (c) = k, and -1/(K-1) if $c \not = k$.

#### Step 3: Compute error:

$error^{(m)} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{nl+nu}w_{j}^{(m-1)}}{\sum_{i=1}^{nl+nu}w_{i}^{(m-1)}},\ j\ \epsilon \{j|c_{j} \not = P^{(m)}(x_{j}), j = 1,2,...,nl + nu\}$

Error is calculated by summing all of the weights where P $\not =$ the predicted class and then dividing by the total for all of the weights

#### Step 4:

If $error^{(m)} > (K-1)/(K)$, exit

#### Step 5: Set:

$\beta^{(m)}=\frac{(K-1)^{2}}{K} \ast (log(\frac{(1-error^{(m)})}{error^{(m)}})+log(K-1))$

#### Step 6: Update weights:

Weights for labeled samples

$ \alpha * w_{i}^{(m-1)} * exp(\frac{-\beta^{(m)}}{(K-1)^2})$,

if $i\ \epsilon \{i | c_{i} \not = P^{(m)}(x_{i})\
i = 1,2,...,n_{l}\}$

Weights for unlabeled samples

$ w_{i}^{(m-1)} * exp(\frac{-\beta^{(m)}}{(K-1)^2})$

if $i\ \epsilon \{i | c_{i} \not = P^{(m)}(x_{i})\
i = n_{l} + 1,n_{l}+2,...,n_{l} + n_{u}\}$

Only weights for samples that were misclassified are updated. Labeled samples are multiplied by a constant value alpha as stated in the paper. Weights for samples that were correctly classified are not changed.

#### Step 7: Normalize $w_{i}^{(m)}$

$w_{i}^{(m)} * \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_{l}+n_{u}}\ w_{i}^{(m-1)}} {\sum_{i}^{n_{l}+n_{u}}\ w_{i=1}^{(m)}}$,
$i = 1,2,...,n_{l} + n_{u}$

#### Step 8: Update

$H^{(m)}(x) = H^{(m-1)}(x) + \beta^{(m)}(x) h^{(m)}(x)$

H is initialized at the beginning using a zero vector of size $n_{l} + n_{u}$. $h^{(m)}$ is essentially the value of P(x) as determined at each iteration of m. So H is updated by adding the product of beta and h to its previous value (m-1). This process is repeated for a set number of iterations at which time H is reconverted into its respective class based upon the index position where k = 1.

Comment: what is your precise question? Otherwise I's say the post is too vague and might be closed.

Comment: Is my interpretation of the steps of the algorithm correct? Is there another way to get guidance on how to implement this algorithm without running the risk of being vague?

Comment: I suggest you ask: in step i, I am not sure that this is correct, because...